# Android Custom inputs having same IDs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I've built a custom editText component by extending LinearLayout and aligning a textview and an editText. I reuse them for building multiple input programmatically.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_input_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/very_small_margin"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
    android:textColor="@color/input_label_color" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/text_input_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_input_bg"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_margin"/>
</merge>
```

The problem is that with this way of rendering inputs, I endup with editText sharing the same ID and when I leave the fragment containing them and I come back, the editText all has the same values. Even setting their ID to random int does not work.

What can I do to ?
Thanks for any kind of advice or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defined the id to View.NO_ID
And it seems that the problem is now solved.